# Getting Backend error. Please try again. from bq when running a SELECT into a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I seem to be intermittently receiving the following error:

BigQuery error in query operation: Backend error. Please try again.

When I run queries that look like this:

SELECT campaign_id, cookie, point_type FROM myproject.mytable WHERE campaign_id IN ( [CSV list of ids] ) GROUP BY cookie, point_type, campaign_id

With the following bq command:

bq --format=none query --destination_table=myproject.mytable_unique [query]

The errors seem to happen randomly though, the exact same query will work a couple of minutes later. Any idea what is causing this?

The Job Ids for a recent failed job is job_3c05e162605342acb64fce6f71bb8b71

Comment: Just an FYI -- the underlying issue causing this problem has been resolved. Please let us know if you continue to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this job actually succeeded -- what you're seeing is that when bq tries to get the status of the job, the call fails. We're investigating the issue. If you run `bq show -j job_3c05e162605342acb64fce6f71bb8b71`, you should see that the job completed successfully.